# VS2015 access denied to obj folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015, access-denied

I'm having trouble with VS2015 Community Edition. 
Since a day or two the following error appears:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       can't open 'D:\BridgeItDevelopment 31\Applications\ControlViewer\obj\Release\ControlViewer.exe' for writing: Access to the path 'D:\BridgeItDevelopment 31\Applications\ControlViewer\obj\Release\ControlViewer.exe' is denied. ControlViewer   D:\BridgeItDevelopment 31\Applications\ControlViewer\vbc
I cannot find a solution on the internet, and I cannot go on working.
Does anyone know where this error comes from and how to get rid of it?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Make sure that you have access to the obj/ folder and ControlViewer.exe is not read only

Comment: I've done all that, checked it, but no improvement. In the end reinstalled VS2015. Did not help either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 can't open project.exe for writing. Access to path denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353300/visual-studio-2015-cant-open-project-exe-for-writing-access-to-path-denied)